# How do I implement Linenoise4Java?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a project where the command line editor [Linenoise4Java](https://github.com/wangzhengbo/Linenoise4Java) will be useful. I currently have a simple maven project. Where do I start with adding the editor to my project?

Comment: With a comment in the project to release the lib as an artifact in Central repository which I think does not exist in central.

Comment: @khmarbaise Are there any other options? The developer is no longer active, so moving it to maven central is not an option.

Comment: You can fork the project on github and clone to your machine and do an installation but If I remember correctly that was an Ant based build... it's little bit of work....  I would suggest to search if there are alternatives available...